# Setting a property of View Model inside AfterMap method (AutoMapper) asynchronously

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, many-to-many, automapper

In my database I have tables of tags and posts. There is many-to-many relation between them. In Tag entity I don't store number of how many times the tag was used. This property (`Quantity`) is inside tag view model.

By using `AutoMapper` I create a map between `Tag` and `TagViewModel`. Inside `AfterMap` method I set `Quantity` property:

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<Tag, TagViewModel>()
        .AfterMap(async (m, vm) =>
        {
            vm.Quantity = await tagRepository.CountById(vm.Id);
        });
});
```

The problem is, that this code doesn't always work. Sometimes `Quantity` is set properly, sometimes is set as 0 and sometimes I get an exception:

```
BeginExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.
```

How can I fix this problem or what is a better solution to set value of `Quantity` automatically after mapping?

Here is the rest of my code:

Entities:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TagPost> TagPost { get; set; } = new HashSet<TagPost>();
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TagPost> TagPost { get; set; } = new HashSet<TagPost>();
}

public class TagThread
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Tag view model:

```
public class TagViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<int> CountById(int id)
{
    var quantity = await context.Tags
        .SelectMany(t => t.TagPost.Where(c => c.TagId == id))
        .CountAsync();

    return quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a navigation property on your Tag class, so why not just do this:

```
config.CreateMap<Tag, TagViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Quantity, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.TagPost.Count);
```

Comment: Yes, but this should be used with ProjectTo.

Comment: ProjectTo works with MapFrom, as MapFrom accepts an Expression<Func<T>>, so it can be transpiled into SQL. If I had used ResolveUsing, it would not be an Expression<Func<T>>.

Comment: Yes, I was just saying that should be a part of your answer, as the question implies Map, because it has that AfterMap.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Your question is around an asynchronous AfterMap not working. I have simplified your code to make it work

Comment: There was async method executed inside AfterMap which probably generated the problem - thats the reason of the title body. In Tag repository, where is query for tag now I incude TagPost and your solution is working. Thank you for help.